# UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification not working on simulator iOS 9.3, does work on device

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an observer for UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification that gets triggerd when a user changes the font-size under settings -> accessibility.

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "preferredContentSizeChanged:", name: UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

I've never experienced any problems with this before, but now i am having problems with it on the iphone simulator iOS 9.3. It works however on a real device with iOS 9.3.

The simulator returns

```
bogus value for UIPreferredContentSizeCategoryName: (null)
```

Has anyone else experienced the same problem?

Comment: Yes, same here. File a radar, add to OpenRadar and mark as Duplicate.
http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6083508816576512
http://www.openradar.me/faq

Comment: Works on device running 9.3. Does not work on Simulator with 9.3.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, too. But it doesn't work when I change simulator to 9.1-9.2.

Comment: Same here. Obviously a bug.

Comment: Works in 9.1 for me.

Comment: Just lost two hours for this stupidity.
Billion dollars company... and they cannot properly check a new release. In this situation, where is hope?

Comment: Seriously, Apple?! Seriously! Just wasted more than an hour on this ..

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a bug in iOS, I have written this:

```
print(UIApplication.sharedApplication().preferredContentSizeCategory)
```

And I found, when the app is running on a real device with iOS 9.3, the console info could be `UICTContentSizeCategoryXXXL、UICTContentSizeCategoryXXL、UICTContentSizeCategoryXL、UICTContentSizeCategoryL、UICTContentSizeCategoryM、UICTContentSizeCategoryS、UICTContentSizeCategoryXS`

But when the app in running on iOS simulator with iOS 9.3, the console info is always `UICTContentSizeCategoryL`, no matter what font size I chose in settings.